# Changing Background Color Using JQuery on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hover

I'm currently coding and programming a website using Ruby on Rails but having some issues with a fairly basic element within the page. Basically, my backend system will contain a color that will change each month, that color is then pulled and used throughout the website for multiple elements. This is one of those elements...

I have a div with an image inside that will soon be a link. I want to use JS or JQuery to make this element change it's background color on hover. I know it's simple but, for some reason, I can't figure this out. I'll include a jsfiddle of the entire setup:

HTML:

```
<div class="contribute_buttons">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static-passenger2/images/shop_and_support.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contribute_buttons {
    width: 300px;
    height: 39px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #393839;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colorOrig=$(".contribute_buttons").css('background');
    $(".contribute_buttons").hover(
    function() {
        //mouse over
        $(this).css('background', '#AAEE00')
    }, function() {
        //mouse out
        $(this).css('background', colorOrig)
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EQeMs/

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you checked console in that fiddle?

Comment: You fiddle doesn't work because you are not including a jQuery library. http://jsfiddle.net/EQeMs/1/ Works for me.

Comment: Didn't realize that, been staring too long at this -_- thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS using the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) pseudo-class:

```
.contribute_buttons:hover {
    background-color: #AAEE00;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EQeMs/3/)**

Otherwise, your jQuery is fine. It looks like you just forgot to import jQuery in your jsFiddle example.

Comment: Forgot to add: I am concerned with compatibility so, if I can use js or jquery for this, I would prefer that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean browser compatibility? Unless you need to support IE6 (which you shouldn't unless you're in an enterprise that hasn't upgraded yet), this CSS approach will be just as compatible as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Load jQuery in the Frameworks & Extensions menu on the left and this fiddle works fine. $ is the jQuery function and when you see it it means that jQuery is required.

However, unless you're targeting IE below version 7 I would just use the pure CSS solution with :hover